# Split array into custom format pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, text-formatting

I have a dataframe, where certain columns have array type data, this array has elements separated by semicolon(;)  ie when i print df['column_name'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8yvO.png)[0] i.e first element in the array it will print all the values in the array as its semicolon separated.

what data i have :

```
[the sun is a star; there are 8 planets; the big bang]
```

sample dataframe:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8yvO.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADLVo.png)
what i want :

```
Statements: 
(1) the sun is a star
(2) there are 8 planets
(3) the big bang
```

Note: each array may have multiple elements separated by semicolon, not just 3.

What i am trying :

```
for dis_col in dissss_data.columns[2:]:
    dissss_data=dissss_data.withColumn(dis_col,when(F.col(dis_col)!='',F.format_string(str(prefix_var)+': \n%s',dis_col)).otherwise(F.col(dis_col)))
```

What I am getting:

```
Statements: 
the sun is a star;there are 8 planets;the big bang
```

Comment: Do you have a pandas or a spark dataframe?

Comment: Its a Spark dataframe

Comment: what's the data type of the source column(s)?